# Replace particular text after the page is loaded with jquery

Tags: jquery, replace

Is it possible to replace exact text with other text after the page has loaded with jquery?

For example, my data is being generated dynamically within a php loop. Once it finishes outputting the information, I'd like to do a find and replace, replacing the phrase "test phrase 1" with "test phrase 2" throughout the page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need yet another plugin for this task.

The jQuery function .replace() is just fine for that. You can use it on any attribut or text. Example:

```
var href = $this.attr("href").replace(/param\/.*\//, "param/newparam/");
```

This - using regex - takes an url and replaces the first occurance of `param/anything/` with `param/newparam`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find [jquery-translate](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/) useful. It even has method that you need, namely: $().[nodesContainingText](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/wiki/NodesContainingText)(...)